# Glassfish server, JAX-RS and JSON - SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json when including the "long" type in my class

Tags: java, json, web-services, glassfish, jax-rs

I have the following class:

```
public class Destination implements Serializable {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String url;
    //private float latitude;
    //private float longitude;

    public void setId(int id) {this.id = id;}

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUrl() {return url;}

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    /* public float getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(float latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public float getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(float longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }*/
}
```

The following resource:

```
@Path("/destination")
public class DestinationResource {

    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Destination getAllDestinations() throws Exception{

        Destination dest = new Destination();
        dest.setId(1);
        dest.setUrl("asdd");
        dest.setName("Milan");
        // dest.setLatitude(2);
        // dest.setLongitude(13);
        return dest;

    }
}
```

And my pom.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0       

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" 
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>cz.fel.cvut.aos</groupId>
<artifactId>aos_project</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>aos_project</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <version.jdk>1.8</version.jdk>  <!-- 1.7 for JDK 7 -->
    <version.mvn.compiler>3.2</version.mvn.compiler>
    <version.mvn.war.plugin>2.6</version.mvn.war.plugin>
    <version.jersey>2.15</version.jersey>
    <version.servlet.api>3.1.0</version.servlet.api>  <!-- use 3.0.1 for Tomcat 7 or Java EE 6 (i.e. Glassfish 3.x) -->                
</properties>

<repositories>

    <repository>
        <id>java.net-Public</id>
        <name>Maven Java Net Snapshots and Releases</name>
        <url>https://maven.java.net/content/groups/public/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>Central</id>
        <name>Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Central Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <url>http://download.eclipse.org/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo/</url>
        <id>eclipselink</id>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <name>Repository for library EclipseLink (JPA 2.0)</name>
    </repository>

</repositories>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${version.servlet.api}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency> 

    <!-- Jersey -->     
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${version.jersey}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        <version>${version.jersey}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-processing</artifactId>
        <version>${version.jersey}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>${version.jersey}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-sse</artifactId>
        <version>${version.jersey}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- if you are using Jersey client specific features -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>${version.jersey}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.mvn.compiler}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${version.jdk}</source>
                <target>${version.jdk}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.mvn.war.plugin}</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>true</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <archive>
                    <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

I'm running on Glassfish 4 and Jersey 2.5.

My goal is to make a REST application which returns JSON. The code I provided above works without problems - upon performing a GET request, data in the JSON format is returned.

However, if I include a field of the `long` (or `float`, as commented out) data type in the class, any GET request returns a 500 internal server error, described as:

> SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json

in the server log.

What could be causing this?

Comment: What do you have `int` here `public void setLongitude(int longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }`?

Comment: It's a mistake from when I was fiddling around with the data types. I'll edit it now.